# How to update HTC One X (AT&T) without the SIM?

Tags: htc-one-x, att

### I tried clicking 'software update'

http://1drv.ms/1fJ5B3h *(short video showing steps I've done)*

http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-one-x-att/news/

> Navigate to the Home screen then tap All apps > Settings > About > Software Information and locate the Software version. If your Software number is less than 5.18.502.1, you should proceed with the upgrade.

### I tried updating via 'HTC sync'

[image]

---

This phone belongs to my employer and I was advised agains breaking the warranty. So the recommended / official way of updating software is preferred.

I tried inserting another (not AT&T) SIM and it tells me that it is locked. Is that a case that software update doesn't work without the SIM?

Comment: What happened when you tried to upgrade without the SIM?

Comment: @BobbyAlexander - see the video (link on top of the question). I keep pressing 'software update' and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try updating from the phone directly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand the question: http://i.imgur.com/1TWArne.png

Comment: In your phone settings, there will be an option to perform an update. Try that.